# Como posso saber quando o usuário tocou fora do EditText?

Tags: java, android

Eu preciso identificar quando isso acontece.

Eu tenho dois EditTexts, quando o usuário digita a hora e o minuto e tocar em outro EditText a exemplo nome, eu preciso que apareça um aviso caso a hora seja incorreta.

Eu tenho a função que verifica a hora e talz.

Comment: Provavelmente algum evento de focuslost, deve ter algo assim pro campo.

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10627231/5524514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando o método `onFocusChange` voce pode estar fazendo esta funcionalidade:

```
 editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {          

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
               Toast.makeText(getContext, "Saiu do EditText", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```